# Parent div cut the child div using clip path

Tags: html, css, clip-path

I am trying to cut background color using clip path. It's working but the issue is it's also cut the child div.

I added the clip path to the parent div that's the reason I am getting this issue.
 Should I use the `: before` or `: after`?

Or is there any other way to handle this using CSS? 
Would you help me out with this issue?

[image]

```css
.wrapper {
  margin-top: 50px;
}

.demo {
  background-color: red;
  padding: 50px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(100% 0, 100% 49%, 0 100%, 0 1%);
  clip-path: polygon(100% 0, 100% 49%, 0 100%, 0 1%);
}

.demo_content {
  background-color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <section class="demo">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="demo_content">
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute
            irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute
            irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute
            irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute
            irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
</div>
```

Comment: i think its easy to just use pseudo elements

Comment: @ChrisLi, Can you help me with code because I tried .demo:before{content: '';background-color: red;width: 100%;/*clip path code here*/} but it's not working

Comment: I can do that (i think), see my answer below if it's what you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how to do it with pseudo element, make a pseudo element with same height&width, move it to the back, apple clip to it.

```css
.wrapper {
  margin-top: 50px;
}

.demo {
  position: relative;
  padding: 50px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.demo::after {
  content: '';
  background-color: red;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(100% 0, 100% 49%, 0 100%, 0 1%);
  clip-path: polygon(100% 0, 100% 49%, 0 100%, 0 1%);
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: -1;
}

.demo_content {
  background-color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <section class="demo">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="demo_content">
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute
            irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute
            irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute
            irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute
            irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
</div>
```

Comment: Give me some time to implement your code with my code

Comment: Yes, It's working perfectly for me. Thanks, upvote from my side.

Comment: Thank, glad to help

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `clip-path` you can also consider using a gradient as background and you will have better support:

```css
.wrapper {
  margin-top: 50px;
}

.demo {
  background:
   linear-gradient(red,red) top,
   linear-gradient(to bottom right,red 49.8%,transparent 50%) bottom;
  background-size:100% 50%;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  padding: 50px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.demo_content {
  background-color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <section class="demo">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="demo_content">
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute
            irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute
            irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute
            irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute
            irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
</div>
```

Comment: I have clip path -webkit-clip-path: polygon(100% 0, 100% 34%, 0 76%, 0 75%, 0 0);
clip-path: polygon(100% 0, 100% 34%, 0 76%, 0 75%, 0 0); then how can I set with background linear-gradient?

Comment: @how you calculate that? Is there any plugin or tool to check?

Comment: @user9437856 manually, there is no tool ... as you can see you have to gradient, one to create a square shape (placed at the top with a size of 100%x 34%) and another one to create a triangle with a size of (74% - 34%) and placed under the square ... it's a bit difficult at the start but you will get used to it if you adjust values and try it yourself

Comment: @user9437856 show me the gradient you used? with the gradient I gave you shouldn't have space